# Firebase Database setup for Expo project

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

Hey guys please help me understand how to link Firebase to my project on Expo.

I'm trying to create application on React Native.
I found a code, which shows you cards with photos and titles.
But this code uses local data.js file to get the data for web app.

I need to create database instead of this data.js file.

I found many tutorials but I don't know which is really true.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#node.js-apps

This is an official tutorial from Google. If it's true, I should do this:

1. `npm install --save firebase`

to put information into my package.json file

2. Add libraries for Node.js app

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/firestore");
require("firebase/database");
```

3. Add configuration like this:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "API_KEY",
     authDomain: "PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com",
     databaseURL: "https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com",
     projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
     storageBucket: "PROJECT_ID.appspot.com",
     messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID",
     appId: "APP_ID",
     measurementId: "G-MEASUREMENT_ID",
};
```

4. Initialize App

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

If all this steps are true, how then should I start the project?

```
npm start
```

Will it start firebase too?

Also please comment, if there are any mistakes in this steps from Google Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use firebase, you should first create a project on firebase, install firebase on your directory (**yarn add firebase** or **npm i firebase**),

Since this is expo project I do not think you need to add libraries for Node.js,

then in your **app.js/app.tsx** you can run fire base with **firebase.initializeApp(yourConfig)**, this will start firebase,

then simply in your directory run **expo start**